# Is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sin(e^{x-\frac{1}{x}})dx=\frac{\pi}{2}$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I didn't use Glasser's Master Theorem because it only works on even functions, and $\sin(e^x)$ is definitely not an even function.
Here's what I did.
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sin(e^{x-\frac{1}{x}})dx=\int_{-\infty}^{0}\sin(e^{x-\frac{1}{x}})dx+\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin(e^{x-\frac{1}{x}})dx$$
For the first term, $u=-x$ and for the second term, $u=\frac{1}{x}$.
$$=\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin(e^{\frac{1}{x}-x})dx+\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(e^{\frac{1}{x}-x})}{x^2}dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin(e^{\frac{1}{x}-x})\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)dx$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sin(e^{-u})du=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
However, WolframAlpha says that the integral actually approximates to 0.293238...
Did I do something wrong or made an illegal move? If not, does Glasser's Master Theorem work for all kinds of functions, because if so how? Because most proofs I've seen only works for even functions which they don't mention for some reason.

But if my work is wrong though, is there a closed form of this integral or how would you prove that this doesn't equal to $\frac{\pi}{2}$?

Comment: Glasser Master Theorem is *not* just for even functions. It just so happens that for odd functions it is zero, but many functions are neither odd nor even. Proofs of the simplified theorem (without the sum of shifted poles terms) definitely don't use any even properties either. We can go over an example of one you believe that does if you like.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**1.** It is true that Glasser's Master Theorem (GMT) is not directly applicable in this case. However, the reason is not because the integrand is an even function. In fact, **GMT applies to any integrable or non-negative functions on $\mathbb{R}$**, as we can see from the following far-reaching generalization (which actually precedes GMT, so let's give him some credit, too!):

> **Theorem. (Letac, 1977). [1]** Let $\alpha$ be a real number and $\mu$ be a measure on $\mathbb{R}$ which is singular to the Lebesgue measure and satisfies $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{\mu(\mathrm{d}\lambda)}{1+\lambda^2} < \infty$. Then the function
> $$ \phi(x) = x - \alpha - \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \left( \frac{1}{x+i\epsilon - \lambda} + \frac{\lambda}{1+\lambda^2} \right) \, \mu(\mathrm{d}\lambda) $$
> defines a measurable function on $\mathbb{R}$ that preserves the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.

Note that GMT corresponds to the case where $\mu$ is a sum of finitely many point masses.

Returning to OP's integral, GMT is not directly applicable in this case because $\sin(e^u)$ is not Lebesgue integrable. In order to rescue this situation, we may first consider the following regularized version:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sin(e^{x-\frac{1}{x}}) e^{-\varepsilon(x-\frac{1}{x})^2} \, \mathrm{d}x = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sin(e^u) e^{-\varepsilon u^2} \, \mathrm{d}u $$

Here, $\varepsilon > 0$. Now it can be proved that each of the sides is continuous as $\varepsilon \to 0^+$, yielding

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sin(e^{x-\frac{1}{x}}) \, \mathrm{d}x = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sin(e^u) \, \mathrm{d}u = \frac{\pi}{2} $$

as required.

**2.** Naively using Mathematica 14's `NIntegrate` function also yields `0.293238`, but this turns out to be a numerical artifact caused by an inappropriate choice of the approximation scheme for our highly oscillatory integrand $\sin(e^{x-1/x})$. A better approximation indeed yields numerical values close to $\frac{\pi}{2}$. For example, we may evaluate the integral with "near-singularity regions excised":

$$ I_{\varepsilon} := \int_{-\infty}^{-\varepsilon} \sin(e^{x-\frac{1}{x}}) \, \mathrm{d}x + \int_{0}^{1/\varepsilon} \sin(e^{x-\frac{1}{x}}) \, \mathrm{d}x $$

Here, $\varepsilon > 0$ is a sufficiently small number. This works because $I_{\varepsilon}$ converges to the original integral as $\varepsilon \to 0^+$.

Below figure shows the graph of $x \mapsto \sin(e^{x-\frac{1}{x}})$ revealing highly oscillatory nature of its singularities, and shows the value of $I_{0.02}$.

[image: Numerical experiment]

---

<sup>[1] Letac, Gérard. "Which Functions Preserve Cauchy Laws?" *Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society* 67, no. 2 (1977): 277-86. doi:10.2307/2041287.</sup>

<sup>Just a fun fact: [Letac](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/340923/g%c3%a9rard-letac) is also an active user in this MSE community.</sup>

Comment: The master theorem does apply even here, because the statement of the theorem uses the principal value of both sides.

Comment: @NinadMunshi, Of course I believe GMT applies to some principal values, and even the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glasser%27s_master_theorem) claims this to be true. The problem is, *I could not verify this claim in any of the references therein*. Even [Glasser's original paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1983-40-162/S0025-5718-1983-0689471-1/S0025-5718-1983-0689471-1.pdf) proves this only for integrable functions. So I chose to be cautious.